# How to Get the properties tag only using the XPath in PHP & Hash using sha256

Tags: php, xml, xpath, hash, invoice

I have an xml , and i need to get the property tags only and hash it, the sample xml is below

The below is the sample xml file, i need to take property tags mentioned in step 4 and then hash it, the problem is i am not sure how to do that.  in PHP how to get property tags only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"><ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
        <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <!-- Please note that the signature values are sample values only -->
            <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2">
                <sac:SignatureInformation>
                    <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                    <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                            <ds:Reference Id="invoiceSignedData" URI="">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                        <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>F3P8vXLlgfPJAxHYz7LjP+7d2FatgmLNA5HkEy6zfGk=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                            <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>MjdhNzM1ODY0YTRkMTI3NzlmOWRkZGY5NzM2NDMxZTIzOGNjYzQ2Yzk1MGFkOWYwYmIyYzA1ZGQwY2FjZTg4MA==</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>MEQCICWP/3r/7eHM9YeJ6V3FNbjylorXzo2zbYs599KfSwfpAiBGa7iBaRqLe4IBMPRYDbocXU9vsn6+buziVmuIOrH6PA==</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:Object>
                            <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="signature">
                                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                        <xades:SigningTime>2022-07-19T10:24:13Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                        <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                            <xades:Cert>
                                                <xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                                    <ds:DigestValue>NjlhOTVmYzIzN2I0MjcxNGRjNDQ1N2EzM2I5NGNjNDUyZmQ5ZjExMDUwNGM2ODNjNDAxMTQ0ZDk1NDQ4OTRmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                </xades:CertDigest>
                                                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382876776561391517206651645660279462721580</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                            </xades:Cert>
                                        </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                </xades:SignedProperties>
                            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                        </ds:Object>
                    </ds:Signature>
                </sac:SignatureInformation>
            </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
        </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
   
   <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
   <cbc:ID>935</cbc:ID>
   <!-- Please note that the UUID value is a sample value only -->
   <cbc:UUID>3cf5ee18-ee25-44ea-a444-2c37ba7f28be</cbc:UUID>
   <cbc:IssueDate>2021-01-05</cbc:IssueDate>
   <cbc:IssueTime>09:32:40</cbc:IssueTime>
   <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0211010">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
   <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
   <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
   <cac:BillingReference>
      <cac:InvoiceDocumentReference>
         <cbc:ID>”Invoice Number: 354; Invoice Issue Date: 2021-02-10”</cbc:ID>
      </cac:InvoiceDocumentReference>
   </cac:BillingReference>
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:UUID>70</cbc:UUID>
   </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <!-- Please note that the hash value is a sample value only -->
      <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
      <cac:Attachment>
         <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
      </cac:Attachment>
   </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
   
   <!-- Please note that the signature value is a sample value only -->
   
   <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">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</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference><cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
</cac:Signature><cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">1265126534</cbc:ID>
         </cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>Kemarat Street,</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:BuildingNumber>3724</cbc:BuildingNumber>
            <cbc:PlotIdentification>9833</cbc:PlotIdentification>
            <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>ِAlfalah</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
            <cbc:CityName>Jeddah</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>15385</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cbc:CountrySubentity>Makkah</cbc:CountrySubentity>
            <cac:Country>
               <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
         </cac:PostalAddress>
         <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:CompanyID>333333333333333</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
               <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
         </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
         <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>Omar Hospital</cbc:RegistrationName>
         </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="NAT">1010101010</cbc:ID>
         </cac:PartyIdentification>
         <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>Kemarat Street,</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:BuildingNumber>3724</cbc:BuildingNumber>
            <cbc:PlotIdentification>9833</cbc:PlotIdentification>
            <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>ِAlfalah</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
            <cbc:CityName>Jeddah</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>15385</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cbc:CountrySubentity>Makkah</cbc:CountrySubentity>
            <cac:Country>
               <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
         </cac:PostalAddress>
         <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>Sara Hamad</cbc:RegistrationName>
         </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
   <cac:Delivery>
      <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2022-02-10</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
   </cac:Delivery>
   <cac:PaymentMeans>
      <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>42</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
      <cbc:InstructionNote>“Returned items”</cbc:InstructionNote>
   </cac:PaymentMeans>
   <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxSubtotal>
         <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
         <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
         <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>Z</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>VATEX-SA-HEA </cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>Private healthcare to citizen</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
               <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
         </cac:TaxCategory>
      </cac:TaxSubtotal>
   </cac:TaxTotal>
   <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
   </cac:TaxTotal>
   <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
      <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
      <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
   </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cbc:ID>18373428</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cac:TaxTotal>
         <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
         <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
      </cac:TaxTotal>
      <cac:Item>
         <cbc:Name>Surgery</cbc:Name>
         <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>Z</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>0</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
               <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
         </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
      </cac:Item>
      <cac:Price>
         <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">250.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
      </cac:Price>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

> Note: All these values will be used in later steps. Values to be used
> XPath Populated Signed Properties from Step 4

The Xpath is below

```
/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/ sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:- Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:SignedProperties
```

Step 4 : has been completed
Populated Signed Properties are below

```
/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/
xades:SignedProperties/xades:SignedSignatureProperties/
xades:SigningCertificate/xades:Cert/xades:CertDigest/ds:DigestValue

/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/
xades:SignedProperties/xades:SignedSignatureProperties/
xades:SigningTime

/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/
xades:SignedProperties/xades:SignedSignatureProperties/
xades:SigningCertificate/xades:Cert/xades:IssuerSerial/ds:X509IssuerName

/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/
xades:SignedProperties//xades:SignedSignatureProperties/
xades:SigningCertificate/xades:Cert/xades:IssuerSerial/ds:X509SerialNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to not refer the SignedProperties simply by Id? You can try to use:

```
//*[@id="xadesSignedProperties"]
```

Additionally, you may also want to add a canonicalization transform to the SignedProperties's ds:Reference.